# Создание файла с кодировкой UTF-8 C++

Tags: c++, qt, файлы, qtcreator, utf-8

Хочу записать переменную типа char в файл с кодировкой UTF-8, в переменной хранятся символы кириллицы, в этом и есть вся проблема. Если я правильно понимаю, то эта переменная в кодировке ANSI, может как-то можно перевести саму переменную в UTF-8? Это бы тоже решило проблему.
У меня получилось создать "UTF-8 со спецификацией", но это не подходит. Работаю в Qt.

Comment: кириллица в uft-8 занимает 2 байта, то есть, нужно два char. В один не влезет никак.

Comment: но если у Вас Qt - там относительно легко преобразовать с cp1251 в utf-8

Comment: Пишите и читайте бинарные файлы, там кодирока будет *as is* (как есть). Байты кирилицы прийдётся преобразовать в utf-8

Comment: Скорее всего вы работаете в винде?

Answer (score 1):

С кодировками желательно хорошенько разобраться. Есть нюансы, так, по  умолчанию:

- Qt 5 сохраняет текстовые файлы в локальной кодировке. И, соответственно, при считывании считается, что используется локальная кодировка.
- Qt 6 сохраняет текстовые файлы в кодировке utf-8. И, соответственно, при считывании текстовые файлы должны быть в кодировке utf-8.

Раньше в книжках советовали сохранять исходные файлы в кодировке utf-8, а в коде использовать функцию `QObject::trUtf8()`. В Qt 6 больше этой функции нету, а исходные файлы обязаны быть сохранеными в кодировке utf-8. Также есть функция `QString::fromUtf8()`.

Также важно понимать, что в классах `QChar` И `QString` используется кодировка utf-16. Qt сам, под капотом, преобразовывает тексты в данную кодировку и обратно.

Если же нужно получить набор байтов в кодировке utf-8, есть функция `QString::toUtf8()`:

```cpp
QString myString("foo/bar");
QByteArray inUtf8 = myString.toUtf8();
const char *data = inUtf8.constData();
```

И как создавать сам текстовый файл: [unicode - Create UTF-8 file in Qt - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780507/create-utf-8-file-in-qt). Актуально для Qt 5, в Qt 6 нет необходимости дополнительно устанавливать кодировку.